# Multiline timeseries plot in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

How to plot multiline timeseries  in `Bokeh`?
I got an empty chart with no plots using the two pairs of x and y below:

```
x1 = ['2017-03-15', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-17', '2017-03-18', '2017-03-19']
y1 = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.0]

x2 = ['2017-03-20', '2017-03-21', '2017-03-22', '2017-03-23', '2017-03-24']
y2 = [0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25, 0.27]

#converting x-axis to datetime
x1 = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in x1]
x2 = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in x2]

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="my Chart", x_axis_label='date', y_axis_label='percentage', x_axis_type='datetime',tools=TOOLS)

p.multi_line(xs = [x1, y1] , ys = [x2, y2], color=['red','green'])

html = file_html(p, CDN, "my plot")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your xs and ys arguments set incorrectly in the p.multi_line method.

Try this instead:

```
p.multi_line(xs = [x1, x2] , ys = [y1, y2], color=['red','green'])
```

[image]